# Remove To-Do List/filter in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user that is currently using Outlook 2010 and uses Tasks (part of outlook 2010) on a daily basis. We are looking to remove the To-Do List filter from the My Task bar. I've googled for many hours and have come up empty. I am beginning to believe that it is simply not possible?

Would someone be able to confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear you can remove the `To-Do` list.

If you are trying to get Outlook to default to `Task View` rather than `To-Do`, I may have a possible work-around. If you follow the article below it will make Outlook default to `Tasks`.

[image]

Article at SlipStick - [Always use Tasks, not Outlook's To-Do List](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/tasks/remove-todo-list-tasks-list-outlook/)

I'm still trying to figure out code to get the new group to stay minimized.